# jboss + metro + ejb3= java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest

Tags: java, web-services, jboss, ejb-3.0

I am using jboss 4.2.3 with metro. I deploy an EJB 3.0 web service without error but when I try to call its wsdl it throws me:
j`ava.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest`

What is happening? I have servlet-api in the lib.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to take `servlet-api` JAR **out** of your application's `lib` directory. JBoss has its own copy, and yours is conflicting with it.

Answer (score 1):

I found this question while searching for "jboss 4.2.3 ejb NoClassDefFoundError" and so would like to add to this. If you're getting NoClassDefFoundError and the class in question is a superclass of one of your beans, make sure that you have bcel.jar on Ant's library path.